# Android: Search in ListView with ContenProvider

Tags: android, listview

I am confused about searching in my Android App. I populate a `ListView` with Data from my `ContentProvider`.
I integrated a search view. This works fine, yet if the user enters a string in the search, the wrong URI is called:

```
switch(sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case RP_ENTRY_DIRECTORY: 
            break;
        case RP_ENTRY_DIRECTORY_FILTER:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(RpEntry.Columns.SNAME + " LIKE %"+ uri.getLastPathSegment()+"% ");

        case RP_ENTRY_ITEM: 
            long id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);             
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(RpEntry.Columns.SNAME + " LIKE "+ uri.getLastPathSegment());

//              if(selection!=null && !selection.isEmpty())
//                  _selection += " and"+selection;
//              return dbhelper.getReadableDatabase().query(RpEntry.TABLE_NAME,
//                      projection, _selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                break;


private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = 
        new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, RpEntry.CONTENT_DIRECTORY, RP_ENTRY_DIRECTORY);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, RpEntry.CONTENT_DIRECTORY+"/*", RP_ENTRY_DIRECTORY_FILTER);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, RpEntry.CONTENT_DIRECTORY+"/#", RP_ENTRY_ITEM);        
}
```

The app crashes with a `"NumberFormatException"`. E.g. I enter 'a' into the search field. As far as I have studied the google-dev site, this URI should be called: `+"/*",`

In fact the URI `"/#"` is called, and the Exception is thrown.

Any idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: Please edit and properly format your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a break statement in the `RP_ENTRY_DIRECTORY_FILTER` case.